# unable to access candid interface

Tags: blockchain, decentralized-applications, motoko

```
import Debug "mo:base/Debug";

actor bank4{
var currentValue=300;
currentValue:=100;
// Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));


public func topUp(amount:Nat)
{
  currentValue+=amount;
  Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));
};

public func withdraw(amount:Nat)
{
currentValue-=amount;
Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));
}
}
```

was expected to decrease the amount in candid user interface but it suddenly started showing the following error how can it be resolved

An error happened in Candid canister:
Error: Server returned an error:
Code: 400 (Bad Request)
Body: Specified ingress_expiry not within expected range:
Minimum allowed expiry: 2023-06-10 06:53:14.609660573 UTC
Maximum allowed expiry: 2023-06-10 06:58:44.609660573 UTC
Provided expiry:        2023-06-10 07:05:16.390 UTC
Local replica time:     2023-06-10 06:53:14.609662082 UTC

```
at j.query (http://127.0.0.1:4943/index.js:2:10678)
at async http://127.0.0.1:4943/index.js:2:96415
at async getDidJsFromTmpHack (http://127.0.0.1:4943/index.js:2:268041)
at async Object.fetchActor (http://127.0.0.1:4943/index.js:2:265201)
at async http://127.0.0.1:4943/index.js:2:275457
```

[shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiovM.png)